# plotmath in gridarrange title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have ggplot plots in a list, say

```
plts <- list(plt1=qplot(1:10),plt2=qplot(2:3))
```

which I would like to plot using grid.arrange and a title:

```
do.call(grid.arrange,c(plts,top='a title'))
```

The difficulty is I would like some plotmath expressions in that grid.arrange title. If I do

```
do.call(grid.arrange,c(plts,top=expression('a title[2]') ))
```

R coerces the second argument to do.call to an expression type rather than list, and do.call throws an error. I tried setting the class manually to "list" but to no avail. What is the proper way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to manual of `grid.arrange`:

> top   optional string, or grob

so in oder to use expression, you should provide a grob.
for example, If you want to plot `2` as subscript:

```
library(grid)
grid.arrange(grobs = plts,top= grid.text(expression('a' ~ title[2])))
# or
do.call(grid.arrange, list(grobs = plts,top = grid.text(expression('a' ~ title[2])) ))
```