# Using tex expression in grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building several `ggplot` objects and saving them into a list, to display them I use `grid.arrange`, here an example:

```
chain = matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=100)
numParams = ncol(chain)
plots = list()
for (col in 1:numParams) local({
   hist = ggplot()  + geom_density(mapping = aes_(chain[, col]))
   plots[[col]] <<- hist + labs(x="", y="")
  })
title = "A title"
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots, nrow=numParams, top=title))
```

Up to this point everything works fine, however I wish to use `latex2exp` to have a latex expression as title, for example

```
title = TeX("values $\\lambda$")
```

Using this gives me the following error

> Error in do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots, nrow = numRow, top = title)) : second argument must be a list

This is due to the fact that `c(plots, nrow=numParams, top=title)`, when `title` is an expression, returns an expression.

Has anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

EDIT 1: some variants & errors

```
do.call("grid.arrange", list(plots, nrow=2, top=title))
```

gives as error:

> Error in gList(list(nrow = list(data = list(), layers = list(,  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

```
plots["nrow"] = 2
plots["top"] = title
do.call("grid.arrange", plots)
```

gives as error:

> Error in paste("values ", "", lambda, , , , "") : object 'lambda' not found

Comment: Use `list` not `c` in the `do.call` call.

Comment: Do the plots show up? Your question is not reproducible. The first line for instance gives: `Error in rnorm(1000, nrow = 100) : unused argument (nrow = 100)`

Comment: it's matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=100), and no, the plot does not show up!

Comment: The plot shows up for me. Except using latex or textGrob fails. Perhaps find an alternative way to deal with the title?

Comment: the plot shows up if title="A title", not if title=TeX("...")... anyway I would be happy to find alternatives but I'm not really an R user and cannot see how..

Answer (score 0):

Try `title = grid.text(TeX("values $\\lambda$"))` [hat tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604650/plotmath-in-gridarrange-title)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).